# How to profile the performance of a function in VSCode

Tags: c++, go, visual-studio-code

I had written a program in (C++/Golang). How can I find the function which has taken the highest CPU cycle? Objective is to improve the performance of the program being executed.

Comment: You may use CodeXL to measure performance of your code if you work under Windows, or perf in case of Linux.

Comment: Are you open to using go tool pprof?

Comment: @bigdatamann Thank you bigdataman. pprof has resolved my problem. Please add pprof as answer I will mark as best answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oct. 2021, [Hyang-Ah Hana Kim](https://github.com/hyangah) announces ([tweet](https://twitter.com/belbaoverhill/status/1452855103598305283)) that [`pprof`](https://go.dev/blog/pprof) will be integrated to VSCode (through [VSCode Go](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go))

[image: pprof in VSCode]

That will simplify the performance debug of your Go codebase.

That was [part of GoLand](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/04/03/profiling-go-applications-and-tests/) since Apr. 2019, but you now have an open-source free alternative directly in VSCode.

Oct. 28th, 2021: this is now released with [`vscode-go` 0.29.0](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases/tag/v0.29.0).

Answer (score 3):

Please use pprof for profiling CPU.

You can generate the profile using

```
go test -run=xx -bench=. -benchmem -memprofile mem.prof -cpuprofile cpu.prof
```

and then analyze using:

```
go tool pprof del.test cpu.prof
top
```