# how to know the speed and memory capacity consumed of the algorithm with golang

Tags: performance, go

I have 2 golang algorithms, which use a for loop and recursive. how do i know the speed and memory capacity consumed of my two algorithms ?

```
func forLoop(a int){
    for i:=a; i>=0; i--{
        fmt.Println("ForLoop = ",i)
    }

}
```

```
func recursive(a int) int {
    if(a<=0){
        return 0
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Recursive = ",a)
        return recursive(a-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics describes some built in profiling and some other runtime metrics

Comment: Like in every other programming language without tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

First, write two Benchmark test functions, one for calling each algorithm.
See an example in "[Test and benchmark your code in go](https://marcofranssen.nl/test-and-benchmark-your-code-in-go)" from [Marco Franssen](https://marcofranssen.nl/about).

```golang
// main_test.go
func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0 ; i < b.N ; i++ {
    forLoop(100)
  }
}
func BenchmarkRecursive(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0 ; i < b.N ; i++ {
    recursive(100)
  }
}
```

Second, install the [VSCode extension Go Profiling](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaxMedia.go-prof), and you will be able to launch pprof directly from your IDE:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MaxM65dia/vscode-go-prof/master/media/preview.gif]

You can then compare the time spent in each function.

Note: [a better pprof integration is coming with the next version of vscode-go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718418/6309):

[image: vscode go]
(possibly for vscode-go 0.29: check [the releases](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases))